# it is possbile to get the cpu usage of azurevm Throught powershell like metrics

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-virtual-machine

how can we get cpu usage of azure vm to local machine through csv file 
is it possible..?
example:-i would like to get current cpu usage is 50%.

i am able to get single task usage
example : task1=0.20
          task2=6.98
but i am searching whole thing to get 
Can any one please help me

i am able to get cpu usage in base machine
"wmic cpu get loadpercentage"
like the same i am trying for azure vm

Thanks In Advance
Giri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use this command to get the CPU usage:

```
$cpu = gwmi win32_Processor
$Havecpu = "{0:0.0} %" -f $cpu.LoadPercentage
$Havecpu
```

Also if you want to remote run this script, we can use Winrm to run it and copy it to local PC:

```
$username = 'user'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -string 'password' -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $pass
$s = New-PSSession -ConnectionUri 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:5985' -Credential $cred -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck)
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {powershell c:\test.ps1 > c:\jason2.csv}
Copy-Item -Path C:\jason2.csv -Destination D:\test\test12.csv -fromSession $s
```

By the way, here is the `test.ps1` script:

```
  $cpu = gwmi  win32_Processor 
  $men = gwmi  win32_OperatingSystem 
  $Disks = gwmi  win32_logicaldisk -filter "drivetype=3" 
  $Havecpu = "{0:0.0} %" -f $cpu.LoadPercentage 
  $Allmen = "{0:0.0} MB" -f ($men.TotalVisibleMemorySize  / 1KB) 
  $Freemen = "{0:0.0} MB" -f ($men.FreePhysicalMemory  / 1KB) 
  $Permem =  "{0:0.0} %" -f ((($men.TotalVisibleMemorySize-$men.FreePhysicalMemory)/$men.TotalVisibleMemorySize)*100) 
  Write-Host "CPU: $Havecpu"`r`n
  Write-Host "Total Mem:$Allmen"`r`n 
  Write-Host "Left Mem:$Freemen"`r`n
  Write-Host "Used Mem:$Permem"`r`n
  $IpAdd = (Get-WmiObject -class win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter 'ipenabled = "true"').ipaddress[0]
  Write-Host "Ipaddress:$IpAdd"`r`n
```