# I need to write a Powershell script that will function as a "watchdog"

Tags: azure-powershell

Write a Powershell script that will function as a "watchdog" for a VM CPU usage.
The script should have the following functionality:

1. Script should be configured to execute every 5 minutes on VM x.
2. Upon execution - the script should check CPU load against x threshold.

Comment: What have you tried? StackOverflow is not a free code writing website.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to the suggestions mentioned in the below link and you will be able to write your script:
[how to get cpu usage of azure vm throught powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46667074/how-to-get-cpu-usage-of-azure-vm-throught-powershell)

[it is possbile to get the cpu usage of azurevm Throught powershell like metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46729247/it-is-possbile-to-get-the-cpu-usage-of-azurevm-throught-powershell-like-metrics)

[Azure Monitor PowerShell quick start samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/powershell-quickstart-samples)